# Create dynamically class names.Only

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```js
var i = 0;

function Myfunc() {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    var dynamicClass = "x" + i;
    i++;
    el.setAttribute('class', dynamicClass);
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName(dynamicClass);
    newdiv.appendChild(ele);
    for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
        c[j].appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="nextValue">
<div class="x1">a...</div>
<div class="x2">b...</div>
<div class="x3">c...</div>
<input type="button" onclick="Myfunc()" />
```

I want to create dynamically  class names's in a function.
From my experience with Java and **C** I want every time I press the button and I trigger the function to increase the variable `i` (aka change the name of the class as you will see below) and  retain the value of variable `i` to the memory so it can be increased further the next time when the function been triggered again.

```js
function Myfunc(i) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  var dynamicClass = "x" + i;
  i++;
  el.setAttribute('class', dynamicClass); 
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName(dynamicClass);
  
  for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++){
   newdiv.appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x1">a...</div>
<div class="x2">b...</div>

<div class="xn">c...</div>


<input type="button" onclick="Myfunc()"/>
```

How can variable `i` have the previous value?
I am a student yet with almost zero experience with JS if my question sounds trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added data property on the button itself and passed 'this' to the function call to get the button.
No need to maintain global variable or another hidden element: http://jsfiddle.net/h0cuLuty/1/

javascript:

```
 function Myfunc(obj) {
    var i=parseInt(obj.getAttribute('data'),10);
    var existing = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    var txt = document.createTextNode("x"+i);
    el.appendChild(txt);
    var dynamicClass = "x" + i;
    el.setAttribute('class',dynamicClass); 
    existing.appendChild(el);

    i++;
    obj.setAttribute('data',i);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
</div>

<input type="button" data="1" onclick="Myfunc(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h1Lx6zqe/)

Use Hidden element to store nextValue of increment

```
 function Myfunc() {
   var block = document.getElementById('block');
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
   var nextValue=document.getElementById("nextValue").value;
    var dynamicClass="x" + nextValue;
   newDiv.setAttribute("id", dynamicClass); 
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", dynamicClass);
                 newDiv.innerHTML=dynamicClass;
      block.appendChild(newDiv);
     document.getElementById("nextValue").value=++nextValue;        
 }

<form action="" method="get" >
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="nextValue" />
<div id="block">            
<div class="x1">a...</div>
<div class="x2">b...</div>
<div class="xn">c...</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="Myfunc()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: dude does tha works for you?I mean it  really clever and nice but  this does not work...

Answer (score -1):

You can use attribute of the element:

```
function Myfunc() {
    var newdiv = document.getElementById('newDiv');
    var i = newdiv.getAttribute('ind');
    if(i === null) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i = parseInt(i, 10);
    }

    var el = document.createElement('div');
    var dynamicClass = "x" + i;
    i++;
    newdiv.setAttribute('ind', i);
    el.setAttribute('class', dynamicClass); 

    newdiv.appendChild(el);
}

<div id="newDiv">
<div class="x1">a...</div>
<div class="x2">b...</div>
<div class="xn">c...</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="Myfunc()"/>
```

Comment: i tried ...but still no result .can you find the error? please i have stuck 1 week

Comment: Using global variables is not the optimal solution. You should avoid using globals for everything :)

Comment: For this simple example using global variable is not bad idea. It's better than retrieving data from DOM again and again...

Comment: @Vijay in your example you should use parseInt(i,10) as JS may retrieve that data as string, and the result may be unpredictable. (Don't minus my answer, i'm working for reputation, LOL)

Comment: Thanks for the parseInt buddy. Minus doesn't mean I hate you LOL.....it means I do not want to recommend bad practice. Welcome to SO dear :)